# How to repair a jacket whose pocket zip has detached from shell?

Tags: diy, repairs, gore-tex, jackets

I have a light gore-tex jacket. The pocket zip has detached from shell. The jacket is not ripped. Does anyone know how to "repair" it? Are there agencies in US who can do it for me?

Comment: Hi Gabriela, I've modified your question slightly to make it more generic. Let me know if you are OK with these.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you can add a pic of the same. The members might be able to help you out better with this issue.

Comment: Did it simply come unzipped?

Comment: We definitely need more info or a picture to be able to help.  How was the zipper attached originally, i.e. sewn, glued, or heat-welded?

Comment: This might be a better fit on https://crafts.stackexchange.com/.  Either place more information is required.  Many high end jackets they will repair for free.  I have Patagonia rain jacket over 10 years old they just repaired for free.

Answer (score 3):

I have found that many drycleaning/laundry agencies (where you drop off your clothes and pick them up later, not laundromats) will do small repairs/alterations.

Comment: +1. From my POV, that of a klutz when it comes to anything involving sewing, this is the only sensible solution unless one is on a very tight budget.

Answer (score 3):

Sew it back on and tape the seam.

Stitching GoreTEX is the same as stitching any other material, the difference is you want to use Tenara thread, and you waterproof the seams on the inside of the garment after by ironing on GoreTEX seam tape. You can get any seamstress to repair your zipper, they'll probably tape your seam for you as well. If you want to do it yourself, you can purchase seam tape from multiple sites online including ebay and amazon.

Comment: Good answer for non-klutzes and/or those on a very tight budget.